# Free abelian with basis definition

Tags: group-theory, definition, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

Let $F$ be an abelian group and $B$ a subset of $F$. $F$ is free abelian with basis $B$ if and only if the cyclic subgroup $\langle b\rangle $ is infinite cyclic for each $b\in B$ and $F$ is the direct sum of $\langle b\rangle $.

My question is, $\langle b\rangle $ is already infinite, so why does the author need to say that it is "infinite cyclic", especially given that the author states that it is a cyclic subgroup. Why doesn't the author just say the "cyclic subgroup $\langle b\rangle$ is infinite"?

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Yeah! Sounds better to say "cyclic subgroup is infinite" rather than "cyclic subgroup is infinite cyclic".

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure what you mean by “is already infinite”...

Let’s look at the definition, and what we know before we get to that sentence:

> Let $F$ be an abelian group and $B$ a subset of it.

So, we know $F$ is abelian, we know $B$ is a subset. That’s it. We don’t know yet if $F$ is finite or infinite, torsion, torsion-free, or mixed, or anything else. Just that $F$ is abelian.

> $F$ is free abelian with basis $B$ if and only if the *cyclic* subgroup $\langle b\rangle$ is infinite cyclic for each $b\in B$, and $F$ is the direct sum of [the] $\langle b\rangle$.

We know $\langle b\rangle$ is *cyclic*; we do not know it is *infinite*. Perhaps that’s what you meant? That we know it’s cyclic so why do we need ot say it it is infinite *and* cyclic? I suspect that this is just a question of the “name” given to these groups. It is not uncommon to refer to/define the subgroup generated by a non-torsion element as “infinite cyclic”, so you should think of that not as two adjectives describing the group (“it is both infinite and it is cyclic”), but rather as a single compound adjective describing it (“it is infinitecyclic”).

Comment: What i'm trying to ask is ... is the following statement precisely what the author means :"F is free abelian with basis B if and only if the cyclic subgroup <b> is infinite for each b'in B, and F is the direct sum of the <b>$?

Comment: @monoidaltransform: Not only is it what the author means, it is exactly what the author **said**. Your objection seems to be to using “cyclic” twice, but as I noted, it is very common to use “infinite cyclic” as a single term of art to describe a particular group, and not as a conjunction of two properties (infinite and cyclic).

Comment: Thanks! soo much